# Adding new Items to List replacing old Items in List Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I add new item to my list, it will overwrites earlier value. I want to append the list, but it is not happening

```
Container(
  // color: Colors.red,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        // color: Colors.blue,
        child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
          if(_itemCount > 0){
            setState(() {
              _itemCount--;
            });

          }
        }, child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/minus.png"),width: 20,height: 20,),),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text("$_itemCount"),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        //  color: Colors.green,
        child: FlatButton(onPressed: () async{
          setState(() {
            _itemCount++;
          });
          
          cartItemList = [{"index":widget.intex,"itemObj":widget.items,"quantity":_itemCount}];
          print(addedItems(cartItemList));
          
          final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          await prefs.setStringList('itemList', addedItems(cartItemList));
        }, child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/plus.png"),width: 20,height: 20,),),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I have a `ListView`, ListView items will fetch from API, when I click one item I want it add to a list, which I can save in sharedpreference. but every time I click on a button earlier one overwritten by new one.

below is the code to convert the data to JSON format

```
List<String> addedItems(List<dynamic> cartList){
  try {
    var res = cartList.map((v) => json.encode(v)).toList();
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    // Just in case
    return [];
  }
},
```

Output is

1. When I add first item

   ```
    [{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}]
   ```
2. When I add same item again

   ```
    [{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":2}]
   ```

   (quantity increased)
3. When I add a new item

   ```
    [{"itemObj":{"item_price":20.0,"item_name":"English Breakfast","item_img":" ","item_code":"002","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":71,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}]
   ```

   (Where are the DINE SPECIALs?)

---

But I want output like

```
[{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":2},{"item_price":20.0,"item_name":"English Breakfast","item_img":" ","item_code":"002","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":71,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you set list every time you click button like this

```
cartItemList = [{"index":widget.intex,"itemObj":widget.items,"quantity":_itemCount}];
```

maybe you need to do is

```
cartItemList.add({"index":widget.intex,"itemObj":widget.items,"quantity":_itemCount});
```